# Fixing item parameters in MIRT

Tags: r, item-response-theory, mirt

I am trying to estimate a multiple group model where I fix some of the item parameters and estimate the rest. I was expecting that this scenario would allow me to remove the restriction on the reference group, that means, that if I fix the items I don't need to also fix the distribution of the reference group. However, I cannot seem to find a way to do this. The reference group mean and var are set to 0 and 1.

In my code I first use the `pars='values'` to get the parameter data frame, then I modify the item parameters to the values I want to fix and set their 'est' column to FALSE. I also set all the values in the 'est' column pertaining to the group parameters to TRUE.
Then I try to run the model-

```
mod_general <- multipleGroup(MyDat, 1, group ,itemtype = MyItems, invariance=c(common,'free_means','free_var'),pars=MyPars)
```

But I get -

> `Error: pars input does not contain the appropriate classes, which should match pars = 'values'`

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

**Here is a code to reproduce the error**. We are trying to fix the first 10 items, estimate the next 10 items, and freely estimate the two groups so we get their actual means of 1 and -1.

````
    library(mirt)
    
    #Creating two sets of data according to data parameters, where one group has an average ability of 1 and the other group has an average ability of -1
    
params<-data.frame("Item"=paste0("Item",1:20), "a"=c(0.78,2.05,1.43,1.47,1.83,1.24,2.13,2.1,1.58,1.14,0.84,1.72,0.83,0.61,1.06,0.79,0.46,1.73,0.66,1.58), "d"=c(0.26,-1.02,-0.69,-0.53,-0.49,-0.7,0.34,-0.24,-0.63,-0.88,-3.04,-0.81,-0.72,0.13,-1.53,-1.2,-0.91,-2.23,-0.82,-0.27)) 
itemtype<-rep("2PL",20) 
MyThetas1<-rnorm(1000,1,1)#abilities for the first group 
MyThetas2<-rnorm(1000,-1,1)#abilities for the second group
    
#simulate the data for the first group 
data1<-as.data.frame(simdata( params$a,params$d, 1000, itemtype, Theta = MyThetas1))
    
    data1[["group"]]<-"P1"
    
    #simulate the data for the second group 
data2<-as.data.frame(simdata( params$a,params$d, 1000, itemtype, Theta = MyThetas2))
    
    data2[["group"]]<-"P2"
    
    data<-rbind.data.frame(data1,data2) 
group<-data$group
data$group<-NULL
    
    #export the initial parameters' values so we can modify it 
pars<-multipleGroup(data, 1, group ,itemtype, invariance=c(names(data),'free_means','free_vars'),pars='values')
    
    #create the parameters of the first ten items that need to be fixed 
params.to.fix<-data.frame("Item"=paste0("Item_",1:10), "name"=c(rep("a1",10),rep("d",10)), "value"=c(0.83,2.1,1.5,1.51,1.88,1.31,2.18,2.14,1.65,1.17,0.37,-0.91,-0.54,-0.44,-0.39,-0.57,0.44,-0.15,-0.51,-0.82))
    
    #Replacing the values in "pars" according to the values of the items to be fixed 
for(r in 1:nrow(pars)){ ind=which(pars$item[r]==params.to.fix$Item&par$sname[r]==params.to.fix$name) if(length(ind)>0){ 
pars$value[r]<−params.to.fix$value[ind] 
pars$est[r]<-FALSE
 } 
}
    
    item.to.est<-paste0("Item_",11:20)
    
    #just to check that it's working 
    mod<- multipleGroup(data, 1, group ,itemtype, invariance=c(item.to.est,'free_means','free_var'),pars=pars) coef(mod,simplify=T)[["P1"]]$items
    
    #now that we fixed the item parameters, we want to release the abilities of the reference group in order to estimate it 
    pars[pars$item=="GROUP","est"]<-"TRUE"
    
    #now we enter to the "pars" argument the table that we modified, but it throw an error 
    mod<- multipleGroup(data, 1, group ,itemtype, invariance=c(item.to.est,'free_means','free_vars'),pars=pars)
```
````

Comment: A reprex  would be a good place to start as many things could mismatch (e.g. `MyItems`, and `group` may not match the `MyPars` elements).

Comment: I will set up a reprex, but the question is if this is at all possible? meaning- if I fix item parameters, can I ask MIRT to estimate all the groups means and variances, including the reference group? so far I was only able to free the focal groups. MIRT insists on fixing the reference group even if item parameters are fixed. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Yes this is possible by avoiding some of the invariance options and using the syntax input.

Comment: Thank you Phil! We did try to use the syntax input, that is, using the model command, and that seemed to work well- we were able to fix some items and free the hyper-parms for both groups. I wonder if there is also a way to do it by modifying the pars object?

Comment: There's a few things unusual about  the script (e.g., `TRUE  != 'TRUE'` in R). I'd suggest checking the classes first of the input object since this is probably why the function is complaining.